# CPU to 90% for gunicorn process on debian 11 - Django Nginx Gunicorn Supervisor

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

Since 3 days, I have some issues with the CPU usage which is up to 90%.
When I run "top" on command line, I see that CPU usage for gunicorn is very high !
I do not have a lot of trafic on the website.

[image: top]

I have checked the access log et error log, but I do not find anything...

What Could I check to solve this performance issue ?

Thanks

I have checked the logs but I did not find anything.
I work with Django, Nginx, Gunicorn and Supervisor.

Comment: Could you run without gunicorn and see the CPU usage?. Need to see the difference % CPU between 2 way run. Also, provide config gunicorn